# How to use mock $httpBackend to test error branch

Tags: unit-testing, testing, angularjs

I am following the [AngularJS documentation from here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend)

The problem is that the documentation describes only the "success/happy" branch of the code, and there is no example of how to test the "failure" branch.

What I want to do, is to set the precondition for triggering the `$scope.status = 'ERROR!'` code.

Here is a minimal example.

```
// controller
function MyController($scope, $http) {

  this.saveMessage = function(message) {
    $scope.status = 'Saving...';
    $http.post('/add-msg.py', message).success(function(response) {
      $scope.status = '';
    }).error(function() {
      $scope.status = 'ERROR!';
    });
  };
}

// testing controller
var $httpBackend;

beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
  $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
}));

it('should send msg to server', function() {

  $httpBackend.expectPOST('/add-msg.py', 'message content').respond(500, '');

  var controller = scope.$new(MyController);
  $httpBackend.flush();
  controller.saveMessage('message content');
  $httpBackend.flush();

  // Here is the question: How to set $httpBackend.expectPOST to trigger
  // this condition.
  expect(scope.status).toBe('ERROR!');
});

});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are checking a property of the `controller` while you are setting a property of the scope.

If you want to test for `controller.status` in your `expect` call, you should set `this.status` inside your controller instead of `$scope.status`.

On the other hand, if you set `$scope.status` in your controller, then you should use `scope.status` instead of `controller.status` in your `expect` call.

---

UPDATE: I created a working version for you on Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/aaQ7JQV9WlXhou0PYHTn?p=preview

All tests are passing now...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated the example... it was just a copy paste from official documentaton. This does not answer my question. The mock will still call the `success` branch.

Comment: I created a working version on Plunker and added the link to my main answer.

Comment: Thanks. You are a hero! :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Good luck with your project!