# Testing rejected promise in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, promise

I am building AngularJS application and I am trying to unit test it. What I want to test is rejected scenario.

This is the service I am trying to test:

```
.factory('LoginService',['Login', 'consoleService', function(Login, consoleService){
return {
    getActiveUser: function() {
        return Login.query({}).$promise.then(
            function (users) {
                return users[0];
            },
            function (error) {
                consoleService.print(error);
            }
        );
    }
};
```

}]);

I am trying to write unit test for rejected scenario (error occurred). And I want to be sure that print function is gonna be called when some error occurres. I tried different examples, but neither one didn´t work. Does anyone have idea what is correct way to test it?

Answer (score 0):

The Mock rejection service has already been discussed in the below link

[How to use mock $httpBackend to test error branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133165)

Answer (score 0):

You could mock the Login service, then depending on a variable have it call the pass or fail functions.

```
var failLogin;
beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    failLogin = false;        
    var mockLogin = {
        query: function(data) {
            return {
               $promise: {
                   then: function(pass, fail) {
                       if (failLogin) {
                           fail('failure data');
                       } else {
                           pass('pass data');
                       }
                   }
               }
            }
        } 
    } 

    $provide.value('login', mockLogin);
}

it('should pass', function(){
    LoginService.getActiveUser();
    // should pass
});


it('should fail', function(){
    failLogin = true;
    LoginService.getActiveUser();
    // should fail
});
```